# ActivatedRoute .parent is an empty object in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I am getting an empty object back on my route.parent.params on child route.

```
// parent.route.ts
const App_Routes = [
{ path: ':id', component: BoardComponent, 
      children: [
        { path: 'card', loadChildren: './board/cardwall/card/edit-card/edit-card.module#EditCardModule' }
      ] 
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: ':id', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

//Child component
constructor(
   private route: ActivatedRoute
) { 
   this.route.parent.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
       console.log(params);
   });
}
```

This is how you get parent params as I understand it. What am I missing?

The below answer is not the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

As you are passing an id from your parent component,I guess, you want **id** which was in your routing file.

Id got by activated route..

```
this.parentId= this.route.snapshot.params.**id**;
```

Find here on official documentation

[Activated Route in action](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action)